# Risks of full length KCV (components and full keys)?

Tags: cryptanalysis, keys, attack, key-check-value

We have to comply with third-party security requirements for the loading of 3DES keys. I'm a little confused about the reason behind why Key Check Values (KCVs) can't be full length. As KCV are hashes, I'm wondering what the security implication and risks are?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification. Can you provide any details on a double length 3DES key probably being safe? Is there any impact if the full-length KCV of all the shares and the full-length key are all known?

Answer (score 4):

The usual (or at least traditional) blockcipher KCV is **not a hash** but rather the truncated encryption of zero; see [How to obtain KCV from the key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/how-to-obtain-kcv-from-the-key) and [KCV and compatibility with block cipher modes of operation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/kcv-and-compatibility-with-block-cipher-modes-of-operation)

If 3DES (TDEA) key *components* K1,K2,K3 (i.e. **single-length**) (or their shares) are checked separately, a full-length (64-bit) check value on a 56-bit key component **is practical to bruteforce, with small chance of ambiguity**. Similarly for AES-128 where block size equals key size, if 2^128 bruteforce were practical you would be unlikely to get more than a very few candidate keys, which in most situations is a break. For a double-length or triple-length 3DES key, the key is longer than a (full) data block, by 48 or 104 bits; the former is probably safe and the latter definitely so.