Can two different AES keys have the KCV by chance?
I am trying to check KCVs of a few keys.
I am generating the KCV for the keys using the method mentioned here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11873/115990
Question: Can KCVs of two different AES keys be the same? It's a hash but we take only the first 3 bytes so there is a chance right in case there are millions of keys?

Yes, there are many keys with the same KCV value. To be precise, there are $2^{24}$ possible KCV values. This means collisions are unlikely to occur by chance unless you generate $2^{12}$ or so (a few thousand) keys, but could easily be constructed maliciously.

What I have now found with practical data is that the collisions happen quite a lot as only 16 ^ 6 (i.e. 2 ^ 24 as you have mentioned) combinations are possible which is only 16 mill. For a large dataset that's too small and collisions will happen.
